# Android market filtration issue

Tags: android, filtering, android-manifest, google-play, android-market-filtering

I have following manifest:

```
<supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true" />
<compatible-screens>
    <screen android:screenSize="small"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>

    <screen android:screenSize="normal"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>

    <screen android:screenSize="large"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>

    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>
</compatible-screens>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false"/>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="10"/>
```

But still market reports me that application compatible only with nearly half of devices. E.g. some models of Nexus S and Galaxy Tab 7" (Galaxy Tab GT-P1000) are not supported, but in contrary Galaxy Tab 10" (Galaxy Tab 10.1 SHW-M380K) is supported. I'm really confused, what I'm doing wrong?

Full source code for manifest is [available here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=ba29156bbcc9a3cd&resid=BA29156BBCC9A3CD!114&authkey=XP5UViHg9jk%24)

Comment: Maybe this is not only related to screens. Would you post your entire Android Manifest?

Comment: @Shlublu: look above - there's link where source is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To conclude discussion above, recipe was following:

1. Remove all `<supports-screens>`  and `<compatible-screens>` tags from
   manifest
2. Recompile project under SDK as stated in `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion>` (in this case
   Android 1.5)

That's all.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it available on everything, this is enough:

```
    <supports-screens
       android:largeScreens="true"
       android:normalScreens="true"
       android:smallScreens="true"
       android:xlargeScreens="true"
       android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Forget about compatible-screens or read more here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. I tried this combination also and still problem not resolved

Comment: Please post your complete manifest file, because the code I just copy pasted works with my application .. just tried the Samsung Galaxy Tab (7") to be sure.

Comment: Yes, it works with Galaxy Tab 7" but market reports that it doesn't!

Comment: Perhaps its other question like gps, internet, telephone? touch screen or other user permission

Comment: @Bart I have posted full source - look in link above

Comment: I will have a more in-depth look tonight, but I suggest you try: build with 1.6, set android:minSdkVersion="4", remove android.hardware.telephony, remove android.permission.CALL_PHONE, remove compatible-screens and verify if that works. If it does, try adding the permission and uses-feature again ..

Comment: @Bart. Did exactly as you advised and now it works! I mean Galaxy Tab GT-P1000 is in supported devices list. But... My customer who has Galaxy Tab GT-P1000 reports me that market still doesn't permit him downloading/buying - which is weird. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm happy to see your supported devices problem is solved. Concerning your customer. Can he see the application in his Android Market (on the Tab)? Can he see the updated version in the browser? And last but not least, can he install the application from in the browser on his tab? It can take 'some time' before the updates become visible in the Android Market.

Comment: @Bart customer can see from desktop browser application, but can't install. From tab he even can't see application. Update was done 24 hrs ago...

Comment: @Bart I have figured, customer is from Kazakhstan and they have some limitations on market applications availability. So it doesn't related to programming issues, it's another stuff. Thanx a lot!